# Error when calling a method with a4j:poll vs. JSF commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to implement an autoSave function on an edit form using a4j:poll.

My JSF page contains two items that call the same form method: a button and an RichFaces a4j:poll. The button functions properly. The poll fails. The symptom is that when the a4j:poll triggers, the data entity contained in the form is empty. When the button is pressed, the data entity contained in the form has that data that was typed into the fields.

```
<h:form id="patient">
    <h:commandButton 
        styleClass="submit" 
        id="saveInProgress"
        type="submit"
        actionListener="#{sessionState.pForm.saveInProgressAction}"
        value="Save In-Progress" />  

    <a4j:poll 
        interval="300000" 
        id="autoSave" 
        actionListener="#{sessionState.pForm.saveInProgressAction}" />
</h:form>
```

**EDIT(3):**
(Other edits removed, since they are no longer relevant.)

I think what is happening is that when the a4j:poll triggers, processUpdates() never gets called.

How can I call the processUpdates() method from the a4j:poll?

**Edit:**
Can I call processUpdates() from the method I call in the a4j:poll, saveInProgressAction() in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "delegate"? What happens when the poll triggers? (@action is for server-side operations, you can't control client-side behavior with it nor can you use Expression Language like that)

Comment: I've replaced 'delegate' with 'data entity contained in the form'. This project uses the term 'delegate'. I've also changed from action to actionListeners, though the results are the same.

Comment: I think what is happening is that when the poll triggers, processUpdates() never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only the poll component is processed on the server, if you need to process other components (e.g. text fields) you need to use @execute:

```
<a4j:poll execute="@form" />
```

this will process the entire form, but you can use ids if you need it to be more specific.